# When clause context of "bottom panel visibility status" in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode there is a command named `View: Toggle Panel`, it can control the visiblity of bottom panel. So there must be a visibility status of that panel ...

I want to know the visibility status of that panel because I want to make some keybinding myself, using "when-clause".

I tried to read the docs but didn't find an answer.

Is there a "when-clause" of bottom panel visibility status?

Comment: you can get a dump of all the available context variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
panelVisible
sideBarVisible
```

Using the Command Palette command `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` you can see the state of all active context keys in vscode.

1. Open Help/Toggle Developer Tools/Console
2. Trigger `Developer: Inspect Context Keys` (I suggest with both the panel and sideBar visible)
3. Click anywhere in vscode
4. In the Developer Tools console there will be a large object added with all the context keys.  Expand it and do a find <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in the console to look at   `panel` or `visible` and see if something is useful.  And you will find

`panelVisible: true/false`